# How can I ignore long-press on a section header view on UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, header, uicollectionview

My collection view is re-orderable since using `LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout` for its flowLayout object, and I don't want my collection view's section header to respond long-press touch. But I can't check if it's section header or cell in following delegate call.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a check to see what kind of cell user is long pressing:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? SectionClassName {
        return false
    }

}
```